# Using Pin to source in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I love using the Pin to Source feature to create floating watches for my variables, but sometimes I make to many and they clutter up the screen.

I was just messing around with pinning and unpinning some variables to the source, and I noticed that 2 of my variables got grouped up somehow, and I have no idea how I did this.

I can't reproduce it and I was wondering if anyone knows what I'm talking about, if they could explain the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinning multiple properties from the same object will group those properties into a single pin group:
 [image: Pin Sample]

In the picture above I've pinned the `list` variable (`List<string>`) and two properties on the list object.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it would be kind of pointless for me to be able to group unrelated variables in datatips.